# Why one of the pictures in a bracket has a different f-stop value?

Tags: bracketing, fujifilm-x-t20

I am using Fujifilm xt-20. I set up a bracket to use +/- 2ev.

[image]

But I don't know why the first photo (leftmost photo below) has a f/2.8,

[image]

and the rest have f/5.6

[image]

Is it a good thing? Or is it not going to impact the final HDR output?

If it may impact the final HDR outcome, how I can avoid it?

Comment: Are you sure these three frames are from the same bracketed sequence? Most cameras take the brightest image *last*, not first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have been on fully automatic exposure mode (both speed and aperture set to automatic). With f/5.6, the -2 EV image would have had to be exposed for 1/35 sec. and the camera's logic decided that that was too long (as it would have a high chance to be shaky).

So it decided to open up the aperture instead.

As you feared, this is generally not desireable for HDR merges, as the image will have a narrower DoF as the others. But in this case it doesn't look that relevant as you do not have any foreground details.

Next time, set your desired aperture value manually, letting the camera only change the time (and possibly the ISO).